# Selection bias correction and a multinomial logit

Tags: multinomial-distribution, logit, bias, mlogit, bias-correction

I have a data set for a number of people making 2 decisions - where to live; and how many hours to work. For every observation with a non-zero amount of work, there is an observed wage.

I've assigned each person a unique 'choice' representing the combined observed outcomes. There are 8 work outcomes (0 hours, 8 hours ... 56 hours) and 5 location outcomes (Region A, B, C, D, E), giving a total of 5x8 (40) possible choices.

I want to estimate BOTH the utility function driving the decision, and the wage for the people currently not working. So of the 40 possible choices, 5 have no observed wage.

I can see that if I knew all the wages, I could use a mutlinomial logit model (or random parameters logit model) to estimate the utility function (using package mlogit). I also know that if I was just trying to correct the selection bias in the wage estimation, I could use the Heckman procedure, estimate a logit labour supply and then get the unbiased wage equation (using sampleSelection).

I'm interested in combining both, and I was wondering if there was a existing package that enabled the combination of the two?